# how to rename a path in zpool dataset?

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

I have a two disks zfs pool, after moving to a new PC, it has an error:

```
NAME                         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
your-pool2                   DEGRADED     0     0     0
  mirror-0                   DEGRADED     0     0     0
    ata-ST340014AS_5MQ40HNH  ONLINE       0     0     0
    13723435395862585868     FAULTED      0     0     0  was /dev/sdb1
```

looking at this zdb output, the path: '/dev/sdb1' need to be renamed, how to do that? thanks

```
   children[0]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 0
                guid: 10396996927287780263
                path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST340014AS_5MQ40HNH-part1'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 69
                create_txg: 4
            children[1]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 1
                guid: 13723435395862585868
                path: '/dev/sdb1'
                whole_disk: 1
                not_present: 1
                DTL: 68
                create_txg: 4
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming but operating system configuration. You should delete this and ask this on unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a mirror, you have one of two options:

- `zpool detach` the old disk, `zpool attach` the disk again, but now with the correctly specified disk id.
- `zpool replace` the old disk with the same disk, but now specified by the correct disk id.